# Returns of an equally weighted portfolio consisting of any m of the n stocks

Tags: r, combinations, quantmod

I have a portfolio of five shares, I calculate monthly returns and need all possible combination of three stocks at the time, hence 10 combinations.

How do I calculate monthly return for all possible portfolios? I think I need to use 'combn'. But the result I get is just a veeery long list of numbers. Maybe it's in there somewhere but I cant make anything out of all the numbers..
code so far:

```
library('quantmod')
tickers <- c('MSFT','YHOO','ORCL','EBAY','AMZN')
getSymbols(tickers, src='yahoo', from='2015-03-01', to='2016-02-29')
amzn_ret = monthlyReturn(AMZN, type = 'log')
ebay_ret = monthlyReturn(EBAY, type = 'log')
msft_ret = monthlyReturn(MSFT, type = 'log')
orcl_ret = monthlyReturn(ORCL, type = 'log')
yhoo_ret = monthlyReturn(YHOO, type = 'log')
stock_ret = c(amzn_ret, ebay_ret,yhoo_ret,orcl_ret,msft_ret)
combin = combn(stock_ret, 3, sum, simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: What are the weights of the stocks in portfolios?

Comment: Sorry, equally weighted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding your returns as a vector `c`, what you need is either `cbind` or some form of `table`:

```
stock_ret <- data.table(amzn_ret, ebay_ret,yhoo_ret,orcl_ret,msft_ret)
combin <- combn(stock_ret, 3, rowSums, simplify = TRUE)
```

and you probably meant to say `rowSums`?

Comment: Yes I ment rowSums and you probably ment data.frame
Is there a way where I can see what three stocks are in each portfolio?

Comment: To see the name combinations do: `combn(c("amzn","ebay","yhoo","orcl","msft"),3)`. These names must have the same order as was calculated combin.